# uasort() ? - sorting posts from a bank account

Tags: php

How can I sort an array with some posts from a bank account?

I need to sort by three fields: date, amount, accumulated amount

ie.

```
date | amount | accum_amount
01-01-11 500 500 ('amount' + previous 'accum_amount' = 'accum_amount' => 500 + 0 = 500)
01-01-11 100 600 ('amount' + previous 'accum_amount' = 'accum_amount' => 100 + 500 = 600)
01-02-11 -25 575 ('amount' + previous 'accum_amount' = 'accum_amount' => -25 + 600 = 575)
01-02-11 150 725 ('amount' + previous 'accum_amount' = 'accum_amount' => 150 + 575 = 725)
01-03-11 200 925 ('amount' + previous 'accum_amount' = 'accum_amount' => 200 + 725 = 925)
01-04-11 -25 900 ('amount' + previous 'accum_amount' = 'accum_amount' => -25 + 925 = 900)
```

btw. the date field is an UNIX timestamp

```
array(
    array(
        'time' => 1200000000,
        'amount' => 500,
        'accum_amount' => 500
        ),
    array(
        'time' => 1200000000,
        'amount' => 150,
        'accum_amount' => 725
        ),
    array(
        'time' => 1200000000,
        'amount' => 100,
        'accum_amount' => 600
        ),
    array(
        'time' => 1300000000,
        'amount' => 200,
        'accum_amount' => 925
        ),
    array(
        'time' => 1300000000,
        'amount' => -25,
        'accum_amount' => 900
        ),
    array(
        'time' => 1200000000,
        'amount' => -25,
        'accum_amount' => 575
        )
    )
```

Comment: what would be your desired array??

Comment: How are you getting this data?  This matters -- it might be *easier* to perform the sorting when actually retrieving it.

Comment: yes I know, but this is not possible because the fields isn't added in the right order.. the rows can be added in small groups from different periods

Comment: could you post your array ???

Comment: @user, Of course, if they were in the *right* order, you wouldn't need to sort them.  You say row.  Are you pulling this data from a database?  A relational database?  If so, can you show us the query you use?  The query itself can be modified to provide the output you desire.

Comment: @user, also [you can edit your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/555222) to give yourself a more friendly name than `555222`...

Comment: @Charles On the other hand, there's some serious numerological mojo going on with `555222`

Comment: array added... its used in a bank reconciliation and maybe the user adds back in time.. so its not possible to sort anything in the db

Comment: ... or I don't know if its possible to sort the rows in the query!?

Comment: @clarkk, you can add the query to your question as well, and we can tell you if it can be sorted there.  Also, nice name.

Comment: @clarkk Post some table definition it might be faster like that.

Comment: the query is just as simple as "SELECT time, amount, accum_amount FROM table"

Comment: @clarkk: Then you could do: `SELECT time, amount, accum_amount FROM table ORDER BY time DESC` (or `ASC` depending which order you want). I suggest to learn a bit more about SQL ;) Don't know how good this site is, but it makes a good impression: http://sqlzoo.net/

Comment: @felix.. thats not what I want.. please check my example

Comment: I have added a better description.. please check :)

Comment: @clarkk: Ah ok. You can sort by several fields, that is no problem, just add them to `ORDER BY` to. But I cannot see a pattern in your example. E.g. the second column, for the first date it is sorted in descending order (first 500, then 100) and for the second date it is in ascending order (-25, 150). *EDIT: Ah, could it be you don't want to sort by all three fields at the same time? ;)*

Comment: @felix.. bingo :D amount + previous accum_amount = current accum_amount

Comment: look at the rows as they were your own bank account

Comment: (please don't repost; duplicate deleted)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found another way to do it before the data is put into the db

Answer (score 1):

Change your array structure to something like:

```
$tmp = array(
   time => array(1200000000, 1200000000, 1200000000, ...),
   amount => array(500, 150, 100, ...),
   accum_amount => array(500, 725, 600, ...),
)
```

and then use array_multisort for sorting (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) like:

```
array_multisort($tmp['time'], SORT_ASC, $tmp['amount'], SORT_DESC, $tmp['accum_amount'], SORT_ASC);
```

It's not very intuitive, but it should work.

Of course you can write a helper function to map the new sorting order on other array structure.

Example:

```
function mySort($array, $sort) {
    $tmp = array();
    foreach ($array as $row) {
        foreach ($row as $field => $value) {
            if (!isset($tmp[$field])) {
                $tmp[$field] = array();
            }

            $tmp[$field][] = $value;
        }
    }

    $params = array();
    foreach ($sort as $field => $direction) {
        $params[] = $tmp[$field];
        $params[] = $direction;
    }

    $keys = array_keys($array);
    $params[] =& $keys;

    call_user_func_array('array_multisort', $params);

    $result = array();
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $result[$key] = $array[$key];
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Call:

```
$data = mySort($data, array(
    'time' => SORT_ASC,
    'amount' => SORT_ASC,
    'accum_amount' => SORT_ASC
));
```

Comment: wouldn't that mean that time/account/amount lose all relation to each other? If I'm mistaken, provide a solution. If I am... considering changing your response.

Comment: @Khez, as long as each element in the original combined array-of-hashes has the same keys, splitting them out like that will result in equal-sized arrays.  The indexes of the new arrays will correspond with the old positions -- the data in `$tmp['time'][41]` will correspond to `$tmp['amount'][41]` and `$tmp['accum_amount'][41]`.  This method will *fail* unless all of these values are present in the original data *every single time*.

Comment: @Charles on the contrary, the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) is very clear that `numeric keys will be re-indexed.`. So again I ask. How is this a valid answer ?

Comment: @Khez, check out the examples on the linked manual page -- while the *index numbers* are discarded, the *values* are shuffled around to correspond to the sorting of the first array.  The very first example demonstrates this: 10/1, 100/3, 100/2, 0/4 becomes 0/4, 10/1, 100/2, 100/3.

Comment: even if this works, he shouldnt have to take his nicely structured array apart into 3 parallel arrays.

Comment: I added an example helper function. I think it's problematic that it will temporarily copy the array, but I couldn't come up with something better for now ;)

Comment: it doesn't work in the way I want it to.. you can't just put asc og desc at each field.. please check my question again.. its updated with a better description

Comment: I see what want to do, but in this setup I don't see the need for sorting? Do you need the sorting to calculate accum_amount correclty?

Answer (score 0):

function [usort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) is made for this purpose:

```
usort($data, "my_sort");

function my_sort($row1, $row2) {
  if ($row1['time']<$row2['time']) return -1;
  if ($row1['time']>$row2['time']) return 1;
  if ($row1['amount']<$row2['amount']) return -1;
  if ($row1['amount']>$row2['amount']) return 1;
  if ($row1['accum_amount']<$row2['accum_amount']) return -1;
  if ($row1['accum_amount']>$row2['accum_amount']) return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: he asked specifically for `uasort`, so i guess the original indices are important to him

Comment: im glad you posted that, i had my comparison function backwards and didnt realize til i read yours =P

Comment: @jon_darkstar: I haven't seen any uasort() required, any specification about keys neither. The original problem doesn't note anything about that which probably means that reordered keys are welcome.

Comment: @Skrol29 - its part of the title, although maybe theres no good reason for that

Comment: @jon_darkstar: I agree this is not clear. I'm leaving this question until @Charles give clearer specifications.

Comment: @Skrol - i wasn't suggesting you change anything.  your solution is fine. even if he were to want it switched to `uasort` it would be a grand total of one extra character!  the two functions are used exactly alike

Answer (score 0):

Your example isnt really clear what you want.  You don't describe it this way, but from example it appears you want to sort by date increasing, then accum_amount increasing, then amount (increasing?)

You just have to write a comparison function and pass it to `uasort` along with your array

```
 $comp = function($a,$b) 
         {
            if ($a['date'] != $b['date'])
                 return $a['date'] - $b['date'];
            else if ($a['accum_amount'] != $b['accum_amount']) 
                 return $a['accum_amount'] - $b['accum_amount'];
            return $a['amount'] - $b['amount'];
         }

 uasort($arr, $comp);
```

You might find a function like this helpful.  It will create the comparison function when given an array, in order of importance, of the keys to compare by.  (All ascending, support for descending would necessarily complicate it a good deal)

```
$compMakerAsc = function($l)
                {
                  return function($a, $b) use ($l)
                  {
                    foreach($l as $k)
                    {
                        if ($a[$k] != $b[$k])
                           return $a[$k] - $b[$k]; 
                           //OR return ($a[$k] > $b[$k]) ? 1 : -1; 
                    }
                    return 0;
                 }

$myComp = $compMakerAsc('date', 'accum_amount', 'amount');
$uasort($arr, $myComp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$key = 'accum_amount';

function sortme($a, $b)
{
    global $key;
    if ($a[$key] == $b[$key]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a[$key] < $b[$key]) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($array, "sortme");
```

perhaps this should help. Bad thing, have to define global variable. Complete code!!!

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'time' => 1200000000,
        'amount' => 500,
        'accum_amount' => 500
        ),
    array(
        'time' => 1200000000,
        'amount' => 150,
        'accum_amount' => 725
        ),
    array(
        'time' => 1200000000,
        'amount' => 100,
        'accum_amount' => 600
        ),
    array(
        'time' => 1300000000,
        'amount' => 200,
        'accum_amount' => 925
        ),
    array(
        'time' => 1300000000,
        'amount' => -25,
        'accum_amount' => 900
        ),
    array(
        'time' => 1200000000,
        'amount' => -25,
        'accum_amount' => 575
        )
    );

$key = 'accum_amount';

function sortme($a, $b)
{
    global $key;
    if ($a[$key] == $b[$key]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a[$key] < $b[$key]) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($array, "sortme");

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: it doesn't work in the way I want it to.. you can't just put asc og desc at each field.. please check my question again.. its updated with a better description

Comment: @clarkk well, i am afraid that i don't know the solution then. still, reverting array will give you the DESC view.

Answer (score 0):

Let's combine this from the comments

> the query is just as simple as `SELECT time, amount, accum_amount FROM table`

with this requirement from the original question:

> I need to sort by three fields: date, amount, accumulated amount

Now, there were no requirements stated as to whether the sort is ascending or not.  Let's assume ascending.

```
SELECT time, amount, accum_amount 
  FROM table
 ORDER BY time ASC, amount ASC, accum_amount ASC
```

This will give us all of the data *first* sorted by time.  When the time is identical, it will sort *second* by amount, lowest first and highest last.  When the time *and* amount are identical, it will sort *third* by the accumulated amount, again sorted lowest first, highest last.

Changing the order of operations with the sort is as simple as swapping around the list in the `ORDER BY` clause.  Going from largest to smallest is as easy as switching from `ASC` to `DESC`.

Note how relatively easy this method is in comparison to sorting in PHP.  Whenever you can, let your database give you pre-sorted results.

---

Because I need to leave the site for a few hours, I'm just going to type this up real quick.  I'm operating right now under the assumption that you want to **recalculate the accumulated value**.

Our query is now:

```
SELECT time, amount
  FROM table
 ORDER BY time ASC, amount DESC
```

We'll be a *friendly* bank and perform all deposits (increases in amount) first, then all debits (decreases in amount) last, processing the largest debits later than the smaller debits.

Given `$data` is our array:

```
$running_total = 0;
foreach($data as $index => $row) {
    $data[$index]['accum_amount'] = $running_total + $row['amount'];
    $running_total = $data[$index]['accum_amount'];
}
```

This should successfully rebuild the `accum_amount` list, given the business rules I have outlined above.

Comment: it doesn't work in the way I want it to.. you can't just put asc og desc at each field.. please check my question again.. its updated with a better description

Comment: @clarkk, I don't understand what is different about your question now.  I still see the same three fields in your data, and **you have not specified *how* you want them sorted**.  If you don't want a column sorted, then don't sort it.  Keep in mind that if you don't specify a sort method for each field, the database *will not consistently return the same rows in the same order*, which may lead to unexpected results.

Comment: amount + previous accum_amount = current accum_amount

Comment: @clarkk, that tells me nothing.  What do you want to sort on, please?  The accumulative amount is *already* in your data...

Comment: accum_amount doesn't have to increase but it could decrease if the amount is smaller than 0

Comment: @clarkk, I don't understand.  Let's rewind a bit.  Surely these transactions occur in a specific order, right?  Usually banks process them in one of two ways.  They will either process them all in real-time throughout the day, or they will wait until the end of the day and then sort the transactions (usually credits first, then debits) and process them in that order.  Because your data only includes date information (no times!), I can only assume now that you're trying to do the second thing -- sort the day's transactions and then **recalculate the accumulative value**.  Is this correct?

Comment: the problem is that the user can export the posts from his bank and upload to the db.. unfortunately he needs to have the ability to add posts back in time

Comment: you can only extract a datestamp from the export

Comment: sorry.. yes thats correct.. I need to know the start post and the end post if the user adds more posts.. none of the already existing posts must be overwritten

Comment: in case of the posts are reconciled

Comment: @clarkk, oh wow, I've been operating under the assumption that this has been an academic exercise.  I did not realize that there was actual money involved here.  Unfortunately without knowing how *their* bank sorts the transactions, you're not going to be able to accomplish your goal with accuracy.  Anyway, I've updated my post with a simple method to recalculate the running total.  G'night.  (Edit: Whoops, I fixed a typo in the update.)

Comment: I was afraid of that answer :) the bank sorts the posts according to the time in desc.. but I can't use that after it has been uploaded and imported to the db.. it would have been alot easier if the bank gave each post a unique id